# NetSuite 2015_2 PHP-SDK Two Factor Authentication

Tags: netsuite

We currently have Two Factor Authentication working in the 2017_2 release of the NetSuite PHP Toolkit, but we have some code that has broken due to changes between 2015_2 and 2017_2. It seems that in 2017_2 it is also far easier to set up Two Factor Authentication.

Looking at the code, however I do see references to TokenPassport and TokenPassportSignature, which tells me that I should be able to get TBA working in 2015_2, which would give us time to figure out the rest of the issues.

My question is: How would I actually go about that? I have set $service->passport to the generated TokenPassport object. I know that my TokenPassport object works in **2017_2**, and I assume it would be the same, but I don't know for sure, and I can't seem to find any information up on Elgoog.

ETA: I have seen examples of this working in 2015_2 in Ruby, but not in PHP. The backend is there, but I can't seem to be able to do this in PHP, and the Ruby examples were only snippets.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I solved this for myself, but I may not have done it the "right" way. Here's what I did:

I took the `makeSoapCall` and `setTokenGenerator` methods from the *new* instance of NSPHPClient.php, and I added them to the OLD version. I had to modify the setTokenGenerator method to not require an instance of `iTokenPassportGenerator`, but I could have just as easily copied over that interface as well.

Basically, all that needs to happen is that we need to send the `tokenPassport` header, which the older version of the SDK can *generate* but doesn't have a method to actually *send* that I could find.